# osmnx simplify_graph does not remove all nodes that are not intersections

Tags: python, osmnx

I am using Osmnx to simply my graph. I have tried with both strict True and false, but my graph still has intermediate nodes which are not interactions.

```
G3 = ox.graph_from_file( osm_simplified_file, bidirectional=False,simplify=False, retain_all=False, name='unnamed')
G3 = ox.simplify_graph(G3, strict=False)
G3 = ox.remove_isolated_nodes(G3);
G3 = ox.get_largest_component(G3,strongly=True);
ox.plot_graph(G3,......)
```

[image]

[image]

The road network after simplification still contains nodes with degree two (two neighbors).
How can I completely remove all intermediate nodes which have no intersections?